# Maximize div width in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

How to maximize div width in browser screen in reactjs.

[image]

As you can see there's a small margin in left and right of the div container even I set the width to 100vw. And I use container fluid. How can I maximize the width of div container to fill the width of the browser screen

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the margin of the body of the page is set to 0.

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Also worth mentioning that Bootstrap's container and container-fluid have a small amount of horizontal margin on either side. You might want to override this.